# save spark dataframe to multiple targets parallel

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to write my final dataframe to hdfs and oracle database.
currently once saving to hdfs done, it start writing to rdbms. is there any way to use java threads to save same dataframe to hdfs as well as rdbms parallel.

```
finalDF.write().option("numPartitions", "10").jdbc(url, exatable, jdbcProp);
finalDF.write().mode("OverWrite").insertInto(hiveDBWithTable);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cache finalDF before writing to hdfs and rdbms. Then make sure that enough executors are available for writing simultaneously. If number of partitions in finalDF are p and cores per executors are c, then you need minimum ceilof(p/c)+ceilof(10/c) executors.

Answer (score 0):

df.show and df.write are Actions. Actions occur sequentially in Spark. So, answer is No, not possible standardly unless threads used.

Answer (score 0):

We can use below code to append dataframe values to table

```
        DF.write
        .mode("append")
        .format("jdbc")
        .option("driver", driverProp)
        .option("url", urlDbRawdata)
        .option("dbtable", TABLE_NAME)
        .option("user", userName)
        .option("password", password)
        .option("numPartitions", maxNumberDBPartitions)
        .option("batchsize",batchSize)
        .save()
```